# Working with infinite sequences in $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, fourier-series

Let $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ be the set of all two-sided sequences $(a_i)$ in $\mathbb{C}$, such that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}} |a_n|^2 \lt \infty$.

What considerations do I have to take into account when separating sequences into two sums?

For example, an inner product on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ is defined for $a,b \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$ by $(a,b) = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} a_n \overline{b_n}$ where the overline means complex conjugation.   I want to prove that it's linear in the first variable, i.e. $(\alpha a + b, c) = \alpha(a,c) + (b,c). \ $ In doing so we have the sum $(\alpha a + b, c) = \sum (\alpha a_n + b_n)\overline{c_n}$.  Why is it valid to separate the sum into two:
$ = \alpha \sum a_n\overline{c_n} + \sum b_n\overline{c_n}$ ?  I thought such operations on sequences were sometimes invalid.  Thanks.

Comment: we can separate it if the two sums converges

Comment: You can split this sum, because the sums - the initial, and the parts of the split - are absolutely convergent. Basically, when all involved sums are absolutely convergent, you can split and rearrange as you please.

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, By absolutely convergent, do you mean square-absolutely convergent?

Comment: No. Since you sum over $a_n\overline{c_n}$, it's absolutely convergent: $\sum \lvert a_n\overline{c_n}\rvert < \infty$. Because of $\lvert xy\rvert \leqslant \frac12(\lvert x\rvert^2 + \lvert y\rvert^2)$.

Comment: How do you prove that trick?  I have $|xy| = |x||y| = \frac{1}{2}(|x||y| + |x||y|)$

Comment: I see now, use the $|x| + e = |y|$ trick.